# Where does Oracle Database write diagnostic logs?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am using Oracle Database 12c on CentOS 6.7.

I am used to troubleshooting services like web servers, etc. by looking for log files at /var/log.

I am having a hard time troubleshooting Oracle 12c in a similar manner. For example, say, I get one of the following errors,

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

Are there any additional logs written for such errors that can help diagnose the problem? I have used `oerr` utility to see detailed descriptions of error codes but they are not always useful. Sometimes I would want to see more context around the error or additional data in the logs.

Does Oracle Database write such logs and if so where?

Comment: The database's fundamental log file is named 'alert<ORACLE_SID>.log. The answer by MaxU will help you locate it.  You need to be aware that not everything gets logged. It will not log application errors, and it will not log failed logon attempts.  It only logs that which is relevant to the actual database operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default:

```
$ORACLE_BASE/diag
```

Correction:

Derived from the value of the `$ORACLE_BASE` environment variable. If `$ORACLE_BASE` is not set, then derived from ORACLE_BASE as set by the Oracle Universal Installer. If ORACLE_BASE is not set, then `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/log` is used.

documentation: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn10280.htm#REFRN10280